# How to conditionally use two different SqlDatabase elements?

Tags: sql, authentication, wix

I am trying to solve a problem which surfaced in the making of an installation package. The installation package is written in wix with the help of visual studio 2010. The installation package is creating a database and adds some tables to that database. The problem occurs, when a user executes the installation package and connects to a remote server where the database shall be created. The two participating hosts are not in the same domain, so sql-server authentication has to be used. In the installation package I give the user the ability to choose between Windows- and SQL-Server-authentication. At the moment, the user is presented a dialog in which he can choose one of the two options. The consequence of either option is, that in a file which stores the connection string, a configuration value, namely the `Integrated Security` switch is toggled between `true` and `false`. The problem is, that during installation, the credentials of the user are used to log into the remote sql server. I have to change the installer so that the sql credentials are used. I know i can achieve this by using the following sql element:

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MasterDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" User="SqlUser" />
```

Where the User attribute is assigned the id of a user element provided by the WixUtilExtension:

```
 <util:User Id="SqlUser" Name="[SQLSERVER_USERNAME]" Password="[SQLSERVER_PASSWORD]" />
```

What I don't know is how to create two different SqlDatabase elements, one for Windows- the other for SQL-Authentication with the same name. Ideally I want to have something like this:

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MasterDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" User="SqlUser"><Condition>SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION=1</Condition></sql:SqlDatabase>
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MasterDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master"><Condition>SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION=0</Condition></sql:SqlDatabase>
```

The SqlDatabase element does not allow Condition elements as children, so this has to be done otherwise. But I don't know how. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

You could create two databases (in their own components) and change the action state of said components using a custom action depending on the user's choice.

```
<Component Id="SqlAuthDB" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlAuthDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" 
        Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" User="SqlUser" />
    <util:User Id="SqlUser" Name="[SQLSERVER_USERNAME]" 
        Password="[SQLSERVER_PASSWORD]" />
</Component>

<Component Id="WinAuthDB" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="WinAuthDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" 
        Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" />
</Component>
```

This will most likely affect file costing, and the only workaround I can see, is to disable one of them from the start with a condition that always evaluates to false, such as `<Condition>1=0</Condition>`.

You can then call a custom action that sets the components' action states depending on the value of `SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION`. You can do this by calling [`MsiSetComponentState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa370383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you're using DTF's managed custom actions, this is done by setting `session.Components["ComponentName"].RequestState`.

As a side note, you could preset `SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION` upon reinstall using one of the component's [current install state](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax), done with the `?ComponentName` syntax. If the value is 2, the component is absent, if it's 3, the component is installed.

**UPDATE**

I'd suggest deleting the `User` attribute in the `SqlDatabase` table if the user chooses windows authentication. The sql extension's custom actions run after any UI (even finding the database), so you could run your custom action using a `Publish` element.

I'd just like to point out that the [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/sql_xsd_sqldatabase.htm) seems to say that you can't run an sql statement against a non existing database:

`This allows MSI to install SqlScripts or SqlStrings to already existing databases on the machine. The install will fail if the database does not exist in these cases.`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to create the database per se. I nested the SqlDatabase element under a Fragment, so it serves as locator which I am using in all of my SqlString elements. The SqlString elements take care of creating the databse. They all reference two SqlDatabase Ids though, that is why I asked if there would be a chance to have two SqlDatabase elements with the same id. Maybe I have to rewrite my installer to not use SqlString elements.

Comment: I now have resorted to the solution I was trying to avoid:
I have two DatabaseLocator records for each database that is used. E.g.:
`<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MasterDB" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" />
<sql:SqlDatabase Id="MasterDBSqlAuth" Server="[SQLSERVER_SERVER]" Instance="[SQLSERVER_INSTANCENAME]" Database="master" User="sqlUser"/>`. As you can see, one is using SqlAuthentication and the other omits the User attribute. Every component which contains an SqlString element now is checking the condition SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION and is duplicated.

Comment: Example for the duplicated SqlString Components (Part1):
`<Component Id="DB_CMP" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes">
<sql:SqlString
  Id="SQLString"
  Sequence="1160"
  SqlDb="MasterDB"
  ExecuteOnInstall="yes"
  ContinueOnError="no"
  SQL="GRANT SELECT ON [\[]dbo[\]].[\[]Notiz[\]] TO [\[]user[\]] AS [\[]dbo[\]]"/>
<Condition>
  <![CDATA[SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION=0]]>
</Condition>
</Component>`

Comment: Example for the duplicated SqlString Components (Part2):
`<Component Id="DB_CMP_SqlAuth" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE" KeyPath="yes">
<sql:SqlString
  Id="SqlAuth_SQLString"
  Sequence="1160"
  SqlDb="MasterDBSqlAuth"
  ExecuteOnInstall="yes"
  ContinueOnError="no"
  SQL="GRANT SELECT ON [\[]dbo[\]].[\[]Table[\]] TO [\[]user[\]] AS [\[]dbo[\]]"/>
<Condition>
  <![CDATA[SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATION=1]]>
</Condition>
</Component>`
And My SqlString Table contains 43 entries, so that makes 86 elements I hade to create/modify... very poor solution, so if you know how to do this more efficiently, please reply

Comment: @BdN3504 I edited my post with something that might work using only one locator, although I haven't tested it. It might be easier to maintain than duplicating everything.